# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

When I try to run the Emulator, I get this error ' Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!' I tried this solution:

1) Open SDK Manager (In Android Studio, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager) and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

2) Now go to your SDK directory C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\ and run the file named intelhaxm-android.exe.

This solution opened up a window and the only thing I could do was to remove something and I didn't know if I should remove it. I need help!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue...